# Is there a way to convert this array to a hash without the inject method?

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

```
animals = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]
```

Convert animals to:

```
{'dogs' => 11, 'cats' => 3}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object):

```
=> array =  [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]
=> array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(pet, n), accum| 
=>   accum[pet] += n
=> end
#> {'dogs' => 11, 'cats' => 3}
```

Comment: I agree , the blocks names would read better

Answer (score 3):

I used [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). A better way is to use a *counting hash*, which @Зелёный has done.

```
animals = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]

animals.group_by(&:first).tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].transpose[1].sum } }
  #=> {"dogs"=>11, "cats"=>3}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]
data.dup
    .group_by(&:shift)
    .map { |k, v| [k, v.flatten.reduce(:+)] }
    .to_h
```

With `Hash#merge`:

```
data.reduce({}) do |acc, e|
  acc.merge([e].to_h) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
end

data.each_with_object({}) do |e, acc|
  acc.merge!([e].to_h) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method that is done by iterating through each array element:

```
animals = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]

result = Hash.new(0)

animals.each do |animal|
    result[animal[0]] += animal[1].to_i
end

p result
```

Comment: this is good. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome CJ Jean :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `to_h` method if you are using ruby <= 2.1.

For example:

```rb
animals = [['dogs', 4], ['cats', 3], ['dogs', 7]]
animals.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k,v.transpose.last.reduce(:+)]}.to_h # return {"dogs"=>11, "cats"=>3}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906745/is-there-a-way-to-convert-this-array-to-a-hash-without-the-inject-method#comment74846947_43906834

Comment: i fix the answer.

Comment: `reduce` is an alias of `inject`

Comment: AH!!! Sorry then.